# Accessing a value from a property that is being set in a method to another method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to get the value of the resultingPoints inside this delegate method

```
- (void)perksDetailsViewController:(PerksDetailsViewController *)sender didPassRequiredPoints:(NSNumber *)requiredPoints withCard:(Card *)selectedCard 
{

    double perksPoints = [requiredPoints doubleValue];

    self.resultingPoints = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[selectedCard subtractPoints:perksPoints] ];

    NSLog(@"points remaining %@", self.resultingPoints);
}
```

This works fine but then when I try to access the resultingPoints inside the method below, resultingPoints has a null value, as being said also by the NSLog I placed.

```
- (void) didPressDone:(id)sender {

    PointsResultsViewController *pointsResults = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resultsPointsVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pointsResults animated:YES];

    pointsResults.leftPointsLabel.text = [self.resultingPoints stringValue];

    NSLog(@"hey points left is%@", self.resultingPoints);
}
```

What could be a good way to get the value of the resultingPoints from the first method?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: 
Log outputs

2012-05-02 15:47:48.297 CardWallet[22196:f803] points remaining 900

2012-05-02 15:47:49.291 CardWallet[22196:f803] hey points left is(null)

Comment: just try                                                           - (void) didPressDone:(id)sender {
 NSLog(@"hey points left is%@", self.resultingPoints);
    PointsResultsViewController *pointsResults = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resultsPointsVC"];
 pointsResults.leftPointsLabel.text = [self.resultingPoints stringValue];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pointsResults animated:YES];

   

   
}

Comment: it's simply a copy of the didPressDone method :|

Comment: no it has dfference in logic.U r putting the value to the leftpointslabel only after pushing the view.U have to try to set that before you are pushing the view.

Comment: When does the first method get called, in relation to the second method? What process in your app do these methods represent? It looks like the first method is a delegate method and the second is launching a new view controller, but it isn't clear what goes where.

Comment: @jrturton the first Yep2 you're right. The delegate method gets called first then the second method is a custom method I've done for a UIBarButton. I want the value resultingPoints to be passed on to the next view controller's label value.

Comment: @annu I've tried it yet the resultingPoints value in the didPressDone method is still null.

Comment: @Grauzten just do 1 thing for this time..save that value there in ur delegate method and take that value when u r presenting thr other view using nsuserdefaults.

Comment: what is the data type of ur resultingPoints?

Comment: this is it's property declaration `@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNumber *resultingPoints;`

Comment: Please include the code where you set this view controller as the delegate of the perks detail view controller. I can't see that anywhere here or in your pastebin so I think you are probably using a different instance each time. Include self in your NSLog statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comment:

> this is it's property declaration `@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNumber *resultingPoints;`

This is probably the source of your problem. A weak property will be deallocated and set to `nil` if nothing else is retaining it, which is the case here. Make it a strong property and it will still be around when you push the new view controller.

From the details you've given in chat, you are actually dealing with two different instances of this class. One that is on the screen, and one that is being used as a delegate.

When assigning the delegate, you have to make sure it is the same object that is on the screen. This is best done in prepareForSegue, when the segue's destination view controller is the view controller that is about to appear.

Comment: I changed it to strong, however, my NSLog for the didPressDone method still says that resultingPoints is nil :(

Comment: Note that the delegate method functions well, it does computation. I would just like to know why is it that in the didPressDone the resultingPoints is null.

Comment: Nothing else, only in these methods were the resultingPoints being used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10776/discussion-between-grauzten-and-jrturton)

Comment: How can I put the .m file in a paste bin? I'm sorry it's just my first time to know such thing.

Comment: By the way thanks for replying :) I've been doing a lot of refresh on this post since yesterday to see other's insights

Comment: sure, It's [here](http://pastebin.com/HuRm2cNw). Don't mind the property pointsResultsVC. I didn't used that.